# Why is ng-animate not being evaluated?

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

On Angular 1.2.0-rc2 I have the following setup: http://plnkr.co/edit/t5J5bl?p=preview

However, there is no animation happening. Worst than that, the `ng-animate` is not even being evaluated.

Is there anything else I should be including to use the directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ngAnimate](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive%3angAnimate) directive is no longer used in Angular 1.2.0 (see [this commit](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/81923f1e41560327f7de6e8fddfda0d2612658f3)). Read [this awesome article](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html#what-has-changed-from-1-1-5-to-1-2) to adapt your code to the new animation module.